# How to change context in Django TemplateView based on url

Tags: python, django

I am stuck with an automation problem in that I have a django project with multiple subdomains, one for each council model instance. All of my models have a foreignfield of 'council' and that is how I am filtering the context of the sites by creating a separate view for each council that I add.

However I would like to somehow create a way to automate adding a view class with the right filtered context each time I add a model instance (Council).

Also I will need to add another url in the urlpatterns which again I am stumped maybe a bit of python could help there but the views are my main concern.

in my views:

```
class RedmarleyPageView(TemplateView):

template_name = "index.html"

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    council_no = 1
    context = super (RedmarleyPageView, self).get_context_data (**kwargs)
    context['members'] = Member.objects.filter (council=council_no)
    context['roles'] = Role.objects.filter (council=council_no)
    context['minutes'] = Minute.objects.filter (council=council_no)
    context['agendas'] = Agenda.objects.filter (council=council_no)
    context['documents'] = Document.objects.filter (council=council_no)
    context['articles'] = Article.objects.filter (council=council_no)
    context['councils'] = Council.objects.filter (id=council_no)
    context['settings'] = Setting.objects.filter(council=council_no)
    context['events'] = Event.objects.filter(council=council_no)
    context['eventscategories'] = EventCategory.objects.all()
    return context
```

urls:

```
url(r'^$', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
url(r'^redmarley/', RedmarleyPageView.as_view(), name='redmarley'),
```

Redmarley in this context is the council inst. and I need it to be able to create a view and url like above for each instance.

Comment: Can you provide an example(code)?

Comment: added some code